# Change Controller and Action name according to language selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-routing

I have a Controller with the name "Hem" and Action name is "Om".
And default language i have set Swedish.
So route will be on Swedish site, it's

```
/sv/Hem/Om
```

Now I want to change language to "en" by clicking English in language section.
So route will be set automatically like this way :

```
/en/Home/About
```

But functionality should be work of `/sv/Hem/Om` and In address bar should be display as `/en/Home/About`

Experts can you please help me out.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this way.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "English route",
    "en/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", language = "en" },
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FrenchHome",
    "/sv/Hem/Om",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", language = "fr" }
);
```

or you can do that way:

```
public class GenericRoutes
{
    public string Controller {get;set;}
    public string Action {get;set;}
    public string Url{get;set;}
    public string RouteName{get;set;}
}

public List<GenericRoutes> Routes = new List<GenericRoutes>();

Routes.Add(new GenericRoutes{Cotroller="bl",Action="cl",Url="bl/cl"})

for(int i=0;i<Routes.count();i++) 
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        Routes[i].RouteName,
        Routes[i].Url,
        new { controller = Routes[i].Controller, action = Routes[i].Action },
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say for each and every action i need to right twice time.one for english "en" and another for swedish "sv". ? Can you plz give me effective and efficient way.

Comment: Updated. I have done that way. I wont know better way than this.

Comment: Yes,it looks i can achieve my target without efficient way.But if you can find another perfect way,let me give update.Thanks.(opps i cannot able to give upmark)

Comment: If you get your answer then click right :).  The way is not available in asp.net mvc5 but if you mvc6 then you can see this blog 
http://www.strathweb.com/2015/11/localized-routes-with-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/

Comment: "i cannot able to give upmark" what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 2):

I personally would **avoid** this approach for multilingual sites. Yes it is technically possible to do what you are asking but most sites do not handle multiple languages in this way. ASP.net has had ability to localize pages for a long time and I would recommend this approach instead.

Localization involves putting resource keys in your view template instead of hard coding your strings. Then you would set the culture of your thread, usually by the http accept-language header and the site would chose the appropriate strings for that culture to put into the page view. The only thing you need to maintain then is sets of strings for each language.

The benefit for this approach is that you write your views only once. When you have 2 or even 3 sets of views you run the risk of having those versions of your site diverge. I personally have seen this happen and its a hard problem to get back from. Also you get to separate your "language problem" from whatever problem your website is solving, meaning your domain isn't cluttered with boilerplate code to maintain a fancy language switching technique, instead of going with the solution that's included with the platform.

If you are interested in doing multi-language sites in .net the right way I would recommend learning about Localization and Globalization, here is a good place to start :)

[Beginners Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati)

[Scott Hanselman tutorial - MVC 3 + Jquery version](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)

Comment: It will be helpful if you give an example of applying resources in route. Actually I dont find any great solution to apply in route.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the OP has not already incorporated internationalization into his site. There is nothing wrong with attempting to do the same with the url, especially if it can be done efficiently even if *most* websites don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not an expert. But in order to route user to different controller you can implement custom routing and configure routes dynamically.

To understand how routing works you may consider checking [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/working-with-routes-in-mvc-framework/) out.

Here is a quick trick to do that:

Here is `RegisterRoutes` method which register all routes for application

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{}
```

1. now get current language from url(get first segment of url (en in  your case))
2. query your data source for current language
3. add your routes here from database or any other source using foreach.

.

```
foreach (var route in RouteValues)
{
    route.UniqueName,
    routes.MapRoute("prefix/{controller}/{action}/{id}, 
       new { controller = route.Controller , action = route.Action , id = route.Id  });
}
```

Comment: Will you plz elaborate it..?

Comment: apologize for delay response, please see updated answer.